# Build btpclient with BlueZ Yocto Recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, bluez, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to use the [auto-pts project](https://github.com/auto-pts/auto-pts#readme) to perform automated Bluetooth Testing on an Embedded System. It [requires that the device-under-test have btpclient included](https://github.com/auto-pts/auto-pts/blob/master/autopts/ptsprojects/bluez/README.md) with its BlueZ installation, but I can't figure out to how to btpclient included during the yocto build.

I have BlueZ installing fine with a yocto receipe, and I see references to btpclient, but I don't end up with the btpclient executable on the system after building with yocto.

These are the yocto recipes I am using: https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/recipes-connectivity/bluez5/

How do I modify those receipes to include btpclient in the installation? The other tools that I see listed in the "NOINST_TOOLS_BT" list of the .bb files are getting installed - just not btpclient.

Comment: Have you added `btpclient` to `PACKAGECONFIG`? E.g. `PACKAGECONFIG += "btpclient`" in bluez5_%.bbappend, or similar

Comment: Thanks @skandigraun - I have tried that, and it does not appear to have made any difference. Everything builds successfully, but no btpclient is present.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it - the comment from @skandigraun was helpful. I did indeed need to add `PACKAGECONFIG += "btpclient"` to the .bbappend file, but I ALSO added `--enable-btpclient` to `EXTRA_OECONF:append` in that same file. Then I also changed the last line in the original .bb file to `tools/btpclient` instead of   `${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'btpclient', 'tools/btpclient', '', d)}`.

When I didn't change that last part, I saw the btpclient end up in the build directory, but it was never actually installed into the image.

Comment: `${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'btpclient', 'tools/btpclient', '', d)}` literally means to add `tools/btpclient` if `PACKAGECONFIG` has `btpclient`. Also you SHOULD NEVER EVER make changes to the original layers/recipes. Read point 5 in [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/what-i-wish-id-known.html)

Comment: I know what that line is supposed to do, but without making that change, it wasn't getting installed. For some reason, despite that value being present in PACKAGECONFIG, it clearly wasn't getting picked up by this line. Do you know why that might be? I'm certainly open to other suggestions on how to resolve.

Comment: It is very strange why that line did not get applied with `btpclient` is in `PACKAGECONFIG`, wait a minute, where did you put `PAKAGECONFIG += "btpclient"` ?

Comment: I added it to: recipes-connectivity/bluez5/bluez5_%.bbappend